# Debug is not working on Local Machine for Lambda Project in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I keep getting this error:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly Assembly,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file
> specified.

I have read the documentation and the json function handler is of form ASSEMBLY::TYPE::METHOD.

If I delete the Assembly the debug interface is loaded correctly but when I make a request it throws error:

> Invalid format for function handler string type::FunctionHandler.
> Format is assembly::type-name::method.

Comment: can you add a minimal example of code that causes this issue?  Specifically, a Function Handler?